# Note 3 "Security information" notification

Tags: security, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I've just set up a new Galaxy Note 3 and I keep getting the following notification:

> #### Security information
>
> An application attempted to access system on your device without
>   authorisation. This attempt has been blocked.

[image]

I have no idea what's causing this as there is no application listed as the culprit. Some forums point to disabling Knox as a solution, but I've done that and still get the same. (Anyway, the phone only includes a link to download the full app, so I doubt that would have been it.) I also know that I can hide the notification for 30 days, but that's just hiding the problem, not fixing it.

What is causing this to keep popping up and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Have a google of Samsung Knox, and be prepared to get very annoyed. I had this on my S4 and just rooted the phone and flashed a Knox Free google edition ROM out of frustration. It's here to stay I'm afraid, in some cases it blocks WiFi as being not allowed. Official line: http://www.samsung.com/global/business/mobile/solution/security/samsung-knox   and the reality: http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-samsung-galaxy-s4/329874-galaxy-s4-strange-security-message-since-4-3-update.html